# Lock the word document and open Modal Dialog above the document

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, ms-word, office-interop

In a Windows Forms application I need to open a word document and hide the main form, and above the word document I need to open a Modal Dialog. When the modal dialog is shown, the word should be disabled, meaning that the user can not scroll, or zoom, or write something in the document. The document will be controlled by the modal dialog.

Now I am using a function from user32.dll, with which I set the parent process for the modal dialog, so that when I hide the main form, the modal dialog will remain visible.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr child, IntPtr newParent);
```

The problem is that if I open the modal dialog with `Show()` or `ShowModal()`, I can still have access to the word document, and if I open it with `ShowDialog()`, the form is kinda integrated in the document and I can't click it or focus it.

Can anyone tell me how can I lock the word document and still be able to have access to the modal dialog?

Is there a `Office.Interop.Word` function that can help?

Answer (score 0):

What you describe isn't the way to go... to achieve what you want you need to implement an Office AddIn instead of the WinForms App... for a walkthrough including source code on how to do that see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb157892.aspx

**EDIT - as per comments:**

Another option would be to render the Word Document to a PDF and display that... for editing the Word document you could use [OpenXML from MS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb448854.aspx) (free) and/or [Aspose.Words](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.words-for-.net/default.aspx) (commercial) or similar library...

Comment: I was looking for a faster solution, but it could be that I have no choice. I was thinking at showing the document in PrintPreview, and disable some of the user functionality. For example, I removed the Escape key functionality (that would exited PrintPreview mode), I removed the rulers and the scroll bars, but I don't know how to remove all the users access, like scrolling down, or zooming into the document. And doing this would be so safe, because I could miss something, because there are tons of thing that can be done, and it's difficult to identify and block them all.

Comment: I don't see a faster solution - at least that would be secure... another option would be to generate a PDF and show that instead of the word document... and edit the word document in a hidden Word or via a library like OpenXML or Aspose.Words .

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution would be to write a Word-Addin, but that will be a lot of work, and may not be possible for you at the moment.

I think the second best solution would be to hide Word when you show the modal dialog.

Comment: I can't hide the word, because using some buttons from the form I need to modify, select or move the text of the word document.         I was think of showing the document in PrintPreview, I hided the rulers and the scroll bars. But I don't know what else to deactivate so that the user can't click or do something to the document.       And yes, creating a Word-AddIn that have the modal's form functionality is a lot of work. I'm trying to find a simpler solution, if there is one.

Comment: I see. I wonder why it would be that much a problem if someone would edit the document. Would it hurt if they did? If so, why? Maybe you can fix that, so the user can just edit the document while the form is open, if they want to.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the document can be locked under the form by using the word `vbModal`:

```
Sub AutoOpen()
    frmIntro.Show vbModal
End Sub
```

Comment: Even better, the document can be hidden until the opening form is closed:     ActiveWindow.Visible = False in Sub AutoOpen, followed by,     ActiveWindow.Visible = True when the form is closed.